# A Complex Analysis question?

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that
$$u = e^{-x} (x \sin y - y \cos y)$$
is harmonic, that is, it holds that
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0.$$

Not really sure how to go about this.

Comment: Do you know how to find partial derivatives?

Comment: yeah, the harmonic part just threw me off a bit.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

1. Compute second partial derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$.
2. Compute second partial derivative of $u$ with respect to $y$.
3. Add them together and show the result is $0$.

**EDIT** Just to make sure you recall, a partial derivate differentiates with respect to one variable, while keeping the other constant. So
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[ e^{-x} (x \sin y - y \cos y) \right] \\
 &= e^{-x} \left[ x \frac{\partial [\sin y]}{\partial y}
                - \frac{\partial [y \cos y]}{\partial y}) \right] \\
 &= e^{-x} \left[ x \cos y - \cos y + y \sin y \right].
\end{split}
$$
and you now need to find
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
 = \frac{\partial \left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right]}{\partial y}
$$
and similarly
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
\text{ and }
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
 = \frac{\partial \left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right]}{\partial x}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Identify $u(x,y)$ as the imaginary part of $-z\,\mathrm e^{-z}$, where $z=x+\mathrm iy$.