# A question about complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $$u = e^{-x} (x \sin y- y \cos y)$$ is harmonic, that is, it holds that $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0$$, find $v = v(x, y)$ such that $f(z) = u + iv$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Second time you, or someone else, ask this question in the last two days. you **must* know how to partial differentiate...do you?

Comment: Any insights you wish to share?  If you have tried something, please let us know so we know where to focus our efforts to help.

Comment: I have shown that it is harmonic by partial differentiation, i know i need to use cauchy riemann next but how?

Comment: @Don: The other question was how to show that $u$ was harmonic.

Comment: Isn't that what this question's asking, @CameronBuie ?

Comment: @Don: No. It is asking how to find a harmonic conjugate of $u$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Complex Analysis question?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698034/a-complex-analysis-question)

Comment: Well, I didn't even notice that part indeed, @CameronBuie . Thanks.

Comment: @Mathlovin: No. It's related, but read the whole question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The Cauchy-Riemann equations must hold. That is: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

So, one thing we can immediately conclude is that $$v(x,y)=\int\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\,dy+C+g(x)$$ for some constant $C$ and some function $g$ such that $g(0)=0$. (Why?)

Comment: So, i got f(z)=(e^(-x))*(xsiny-ycosy)+(i(e^(-x))*(2xcosy+2ysiny)). Not sure how to convert it into a function with z?

Comment: **Hint**: For any real $\theta,$ we have $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta.$ From this, we may conclude that for all real $t,$ we have $$\cos t=\frac12(e^{it}+e^{-it})$$ and $$\sin t=\frac1{2i}(e^{it}-e^{-it}).$$ See if that gets you unstuck.